# AWK невозможно безопасно использовать системным администраторам

Tags: awk

Простой пример. Нужно посчитать сумму чисел из входного потока. Откуда пользователь узнает, что `awk` собран с поддержкой больших чисел?

Получается, что легко можно получить некорректные данные. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Для больших чисел используйте ключи `-M, --bignum`.

> Откуда пользователь узнает что awk собран с поддержкой больших чисел?

А зачем пользователю это знать? Это должен предусмотреть разработчик, если ему это нужно учесть в своём скрипте. Посмотреть можно довольно просто:

```
$ awk -V | head -1
GNU Awk 5.2.1, API 3.2, PMA Avon 8-g1, (GNU MPFR 4.2.0, GNU MP 6.2.1)
```

где видим, что присутствует **MPFR** и **MP**, то есть всё ок и с опцией `--bignum` отработает как надо. Да и если используется данная опция для больших чисел, а сам **awk** не скомпилирован с нужными библиотеками, то по идее должно выдать предупреждение (инфа из мана):

```
 -M, --bignum
             Force  arbitrary precision arithmetic on numbers. This
             option has no effect if gawk is not compiled to use the 
             GNU MPFR and GMP libraries.  (In such a case,  gawk  
             is sues a warning.)
```

Ну или вот еще один можно попробовать способ посложнее — [How To Check If MPFR Is Available](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Checking-for-MPFR).